# Python: is it possible to import another text block?

Tags: python

Is `import another_blender_text_block` possible in Blender with Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://developer.blender.org/T65855), importing text block with import directly has been removed. Now we use
`my_module = bpy.data.texts["text.py"].as_module()`

Answer (score 9):

Yes it is possible. Name your text block (with .py on the end, otherwise you can't import it). You can import a text block using the text block's name without it's extension:

```
import mypythonfile
```

Then to run a function use:

```
mypythonfile.functionname()
```

Comment: You mean blend file filename?
It says No module named 'texttest'

Comment: @kivig no, the python file name (without it's extension).

Comment: I might have explained the point poorly - I want to run a script from a text block, that imports another textblock of the same blend file.
Is that possible?

Comment: Hmm... it works for me. Does your first text block (the one your importing) have .py on the end?

Comment: They both reside inside the blend file, that's why I call it a text block not a file :)

Comment: @kivig exactly, but you still need to name the text block with .py on the end.

Comment: According to this [https://developer.blender.org/T65855], now, to import module from another text block you have to use:

my_module = bpy.data.texts["text.py"].as_module()

Answer (score 0):

You just need to import the text object into your current Python script like this:

```
import bpy

# Get the text datablock
text_datablock = bpy.data.texts['animals']

# Get the text content
text_content = text_datablock.lines

print(type(text_content))

# Get the body of text
for i in text_content:
    print(i.body)
```