# Import script as a module

Tags: scripting, import

I have two files in a directory: "render.py" and "functions.py". From blender I use the text editor to run the "render.py" but the question is how to import "functions.py" to the file. This code fails.

```
import functions
```

How can I import in blender so that i can use functions from "functions.py" ?

Answer (score 2):

#### As a textblock

One way to do this is to add `functions.py` as a Text block. Make sure the Text block has a `.py` extension and you can import it directly using `import functions`. [Described here: python-is-it-possible-to-import-another-text-block](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/python-is-it-possible-to-import-another-text-block)

#### As a module

Otherwise, add `functions.py` to `scripts/modules/some_name/functions.py`, then

```
from some_name import functions
```

#### A slight hack

> There's probably an elegant way to do this, but if your stuck...

The render.py could load `functions.py` from a given path into a text block named the same:

```
# render.py #

import bpy   

fp = '/home/zeffii/Desktop/functions.py'

def make_functions_local(fp):
    texts = bpy.data.texts
    t = texts.get('functions.py')
    if not t:
        t = texts.new('functions.py')

    with open(fp) as module_file:
        t.from_string(module_file.read()) 

# trigger it
make_functions_local(fp)

import functions

# your stuff
```

Comment: Well the answer is almost there but the only thing is I would like to avoid putting files into /scripts/smodules/ directory. The perfect answer would be how to import the file in the same directory as the main script.

Comment: Your render.py file is being loaded from disk? I don't think your question made that clear.