# Importing functions from text block in same file

Tags: scripting

I am trying to use a text block from within the same Blender file, following the (rather old) advice here: [Python: is it possible to import another text block?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/python-is-it-possible-to-import-another-text-block)

So I have two text blocks. One called Text and one called printy.py which contains the simplest of functions:

`def printthing():
     print('thing')`

In 'Text', all it says is:

`import bpy
 import printy
 printy.printthing()`

I've saved and reopened the file. But I get: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'printy'`

This seems laughably simple and I've seen the approach in a several places, e.g. [Blender 2.80: Helper Modules](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Modules) but I can't make it work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Might not be a duplicate if desired result is the scripts registered per specific file automatically on loading the file. @edna, is this what you are asking?

Comment: @MartinZ In that case, maybe an older build will suit the need. Could wait for the change: https://developer.blender.org/rBdc8dd24351462e73c5d0260564aad9cd56fd6c33

Comment: @Hikariztw, I think I just misunderstood the question and you are right - it seems to be a duplicate.